# PhpMyAdmin adds WHERE 1 to every statement by default

Tags: phpmyadmin

Just a curiosity question. Why phpMyadmin adds `WHERE 1` to every statement in the SQL query input box?

For example,

```
 SELECT * FROM User WHERE 1
```

Comment: Probably laziness! The code adds `WHERE`, and then when there are no conditions, it adds `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating dynamic queries, it's easier to always have a `WHERE` clause than to have an algorithm to remove it when it's not needed. All that `WHERE 1` means is 'everything' and phpMyAdmin will not append it if you put a `WHERE` clause in your own query.

phpMyAdmin probably creates its queries by concatenating strings, so it'll generate say `$selectStatement`, `$whereStatement` and `$limitStatement` and then add them all together. I don't know if it still does it, but it always used to add a `LIMIT` clause even when not needed as well.

It's just a simple and comprehensive way to build an SQL statement in PHP, and won't affect your query results at all.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that it's a useful guide. I have unfortunately made a couple of mistakes where I forgot to add a `WHERE` clause and wound up having to frantically restore a backup before everyone realises I reset ALL their passwords instead of just one... oops!

Having it there doesn't serve any functional purpose, but it can be a useful reminder before you go and mess up like I did.

Comment: @Oshawott Not really, since it being there would have reminded me to include some kind of `WHERE` clause, rather than it not being there at all.

Comment: Can't say I've ever forgotten. :P I think I'd be more likely to forget to remove the `WHERE 1` than to forget to add another `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This combination of users is kind of funny